# sem_wait() fails with error: success

Tags: c++, process, synchronization, posix, semaphore

Trying to synchronize process on unix using semaphores, `sem_wait()` fails with error "success".

I have 3 process, each of which runs the same code:

```
while( sem_wait( &sem ) == -1 );
    if( errno != EINTR )
    {
        perror("Failed to lock semaphore");
    }
/* critical section */
while( sem_post( &sem ) < 0 )
    {
        perror("Failed to unlock semaphore");
    }
```

`sem_init()` and `sem_destroy()` are called in the parent process, before (and after) the child processes are created. The result is:

```
Failed to lock semaphore: Success
Failed to lock semaphore: Success
Failed to lock semaphore: Success
```

Is `sem_wait()` failing? and if it does, why does it say "success"?

Comment: Is that semicolon at the end of your first while() loop condition intentional?  Because with the semicolon, you won't exit the (null-bodied) while loop until sem_wait returns something other than -1 (i.e until it succeeds)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Oh boy, I can't believe i've made that mistake! Soooooo embarrassing... Well, that's what happens when you code nonstop for 5 hours

Comment: Please review "man sem_wait".  This function returns 0 on success, so you should not be spinning and waiting for a -1.  Also, you do not show your sem_init() or sem_open() call, so we can not tell if the semaphore is shared nor what the initial value is.  You probably need to show more code.

Comment: I think your code is unusual to be spin-waiting for sem_<operation>.  IMHO, a simple if clause is more appropriate.  You only need handle errors when not success, so  "if (SUCCESS != sem_wait(&sem)) { <handle error> } ; // else continue normal flow

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN Thanks, but the issue was the semicolon, as Jeremy noted. The reason for the while loop is to keep trying to lock the semaphore when it fails unless an interrupt is caught. Is that not a right approach?

Comment: I think not.  It is a typical 'bad neighbor' poll (cpu-cycle-sink).  However, if you believe this is important, posix process semaphore also provides a "sem_trywait()"  AND a "sem_timedwait()".  Your spin currently won't stop unless you add a counter.  (infinite-loops are probably un-acceptable.

Comment: @YoavKadosh - I am thinking about changing my mind (about the bad neighbor poll)  When sem_wait returns success, the code will either block (because semaphore already locked) or skip the error handling loop.  I think this might be ok.  My apologies ... either I am slow to evaluate a different way of looking at the issue, or perhaps I just like to do it the way I know works.  I vaguely remember the idea that a process might be locked, then get kicked out of the lock by some signal.  Perhaps your loop might better handle that scenario.  I am pretty sure I never solved it.  Good luck.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN Thank you, I actually saw this way of handling it (the loop) in a book called *unix systems programming* by Robbins. They use this method throughout the book.